# How to use current url in Facebook Social Plugin without PHP?

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-comments

I have seen several solutions but none seem to work since Facebook updated the app and/or use PHP (get_permalink). I need a non-PHP solution, All my pages are static. I just need  data-href="" to be filled in with the Current Url so that I can implement the code across every page on the site that is needed without individually writing in the unique url for every page.

Leaving data-href"" blank worked before 2.0

> ```
>   <div id="fb-root"></div>
>    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
>    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
>    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
>    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
>    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
>
> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="????????????????????????" 
>   data-width="430" data-num-posts="8" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that in the `<head>` or before the `<body>` tag ends for extra speed. Edit the src for jquery,though it's always better to use a online cdn like below:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fb-comments').attr("data-href", document.URL);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did not seem to have any effect, I am not the best with jquery, here's how I implemented. "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/js/jquery.js">
$('.fb-comments').attr("data-href", document.URL);    
    </script>" and then it should have just referenced, the class that fb-comments were already in correct?

Comment: I'm playing with it, It is def. the closest I've been in days. If you refresh, it works perfectly, but on initial page load, it is still pulling up comments using the initial data-href info and not the query replacement  EDIT: Also, thank you so much so far

Comment: AND SOLVED! The Facebook header code was foolishly above the jquery so i flipped em and it works like a charm! I'll come back when I have reputation to up vote. Thanks so much Wololo!